# Compressibility factor (Z) of the Redlich-Kwong Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, mathematical-physics, chemistry

I've been having a problem trying to calculate the compressibility factor of the **Redlich-Kwong equation**:

\begin{equation}
P = \frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{T} \cdot (v^2+vb)}
\end{equation}

The compressibility factor is calculated as:

\begin{equation}
z = \frac{P \cdot v}{RT}
\end{equation}

This factor is calculated if we substitute the molar volume ($v$), but I can't express the Redlich-Kwong equation in terms of $P$ and $T$, that's why I would like to know if some of you guys could help me to isolate the $v$ of this Redlich-Kwong equation. Thanks! :)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: You must rewrite the equation in terms of $Z$ (except if you want major troubles). Moreover, this is what is asked.

Comment: Expressing $v$ requires solving a cubic equation. There is no going around it.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
P &= \frac{RT}{v-b} - \frac{a}{\sqrt{T}(v^2+vb)}\\
&=\frac{RT\sqrt{T}(v^2+vb)-a(v-b)}{\sqrt{T}(v^2+vb)(v-b)}\\
\implies P\sqrt{T}(v^3 - b^2 v)
&-(RT\sqrt{T}(v^2+bv)-av+ab)=0\\
\implies  P \sqrt{T} v^3 - b^2 P \sqrt{T} v
&-a b + a v - b R \sqrt{T^3} v - R \sqrt{T^3} v^2=0 \\
\implies  P \sqrt{T} v^3- R \sqrt{T^3} v^2 
&- \big(b^2 P \sqrt{T}+b R \sqrt{T^3} -a\big)v - a b =0 \\
\end{align*}
We now have a cubic of the form
$\quad ax^3+x^2+cx+d=0\quad$ where
$$a=P \sqrt{T}\quad 
b=- R \sqrt{T^3}\quad 
c=- \big(b^2 P \sqrt{T}+b R \sqrt{T^3} -a\big)\quad 
d=-a$$
and these may be plugged into the
[The Cubic Formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/)
to obtain one real root. The cubic will be a product of this "factor" and a quadratic equation. It's not pretty. The cubic formula looks like this.

\begin{align*}
n&=\sqrt[\huge{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}\\
&+\sqrt[\huge{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}\\
&-\frac{b}{3a}   \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Determine the critical compressibility factor $$=/$$ for a gas obeying

a) Dieterici equation,
b) Berthelot equation,
c) Redlich-Kwong equation.

a) Dieterici equation $=(/(−))−/$,
For which $=422/2$ and $=/2$.

b) Berthelot equation $(+/2)(−)=$,
For which $=(27/64)23/$ and $=/8$.

c) Redlich-Kwong equation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).